# Are Variables Created Inside an IF Statement also Available Outside the IF Statement?

Tags: php, variables

If you have an if statement like this:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
if ($a < $b) {
$c = $a+$b;
}
?>
```

Would you be able to access the $c variable outside of the if statement like so:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
if ($a < $b) {
$c = $a+$b;
}
echo $c
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run that code?

Answer (score 76):

In PHP, `if` doesn't have its own scope. So yes, if you define something inside the `if` statement or inside the block, then it will be available just as if you defined it outside (assuming, of course, the code inside the block or inside the `if` statement gets to run).

To illustrate:

```
if (true)  { $a = 5; }    var_dump($a == 5);   // true
```

The condition evaluates to `true`, so the code inside the block gets run. The variable `$a` gets defined.

```
if (false) { $b = 5; }    var_dump(isset($b)); // false
```

The condition evaluates to `false`, so the code inside the block doesn't get to run. The variable `$b` will not be defined.

```
if ($c = 5) { }           var_dump($c == 5);   // true
```

The code inside the condition gets to run and `$c` gets defined as `5` (`$c = 5`). Even though the assignment happens inside the `if` statement, the value does survive outside, because `if` has no scope. Same thing happens with `for`, just like in, for example, `for ($i = 0, $i < 5; ++$i)`. The `$i` will survive outside the `for` loop, because `for` has no scope either.

```
if (false && $d = 5) { }  var_dump(isset($d)); // false
```

`false` short circuits and the execution does not arrive at `$d = 5`, so the `$d` variable  will not be defined.

For more about the PHP scope, read the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) manual page.

Comment: Good answer but examples (specially `if ($c = 5) {}` one) is enough to confuse anyone.

Comment: @Muhammad Yasir, added explanation.

Comment: So this means i'll have to clean these variables on my own?

Answer (score 13):

PHP's scope is completely function-based.  It's not the same as C or Java where it's local to what block that variables are nested in.

For PHP's scope:

```
// Global variable
$a = 0;

function f()
{
  // Cannot be accessed outside of f()
  if (true)
    $b = 0;

  // However, it can still be accessed anywhere in f()
  $b += 1;
}
```

If you want a variable to be global, simply use the global keyword:

```
// Global variable
$a = 0;

function f()
{
  // Use $a from global scope
  global $a;

  // Modifies global $a
  $a += 1;
}

function g()
{
  // Use $b from global scope, even though it hasn't been defined yet
  global $b;

  // Can be accessed outside of g()
  $b = 0;

  // Cannot be accessed outside of g(); this $a "shadows" the global version
  // The global $a is still 0
  $a = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If the `if` statement containing the variable was executed, then yes, you can access the variable outside of the if statement.  Here's a thought on why it works that way.  In many programming languages you can "declare" a variable before you use it, just to let the compiler know that it's there.  For example in Java you can declare an 'int', then use it like so:

```
int number;
if(true)
    number = 5;
```

In Java, you have to declare a variable like this before using it in an if-then statement.  In php, however, there isn't really a way to do that.  Since php is dynamically typed, you can't write `int $number`.  In Java, the computer allocates a 32 bit block of memory (the size of an int) when the variable is declared.  In php, I believe, the memory is not allocated until something is actually stored in the variable.  The best equivalent to 'declaring' a php variable I could think of would just be to write:

```
$number;    //This is NOT needed
if(true)
    $number = 5;
```

But when you look at the code, it seems kind of strange to just write `$number` like that.  I think the computer would think it was equally strange because as I said before, it is a dynamically typed language, and so it doesn't need to allocate a whole chunk of memory for the number. So you can just leave it like this:

```
if(true)
    $number = 5;
```

Answer (score 4):

Depends.

In PHP chances are yes it would, although of course, if a isnt < b, then c wont exist when you get to the echo c line and your code will complain.

However, in most languages this wouldnt compile for that reason

Comment: Thats why I asked. I usually code objective-c where c wouldn't be accessible outside the scope.