# php getting variable outside if condition

Tags: php

Hi i have little problem with if statements while checking if `$GET` values are sended. The problem is the following: If I run this code the variables in the second if condition becomes inserted but I cant get variables from the second if condition outside the second if condition. Why does that happening? I've already tried it with `return` but it wont work. What is the mistake?

```
$gameid = $_GET['gameid'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$questionid = $_GET['questionid'];

if (isset($_GET['gameid'])) {
$answer = "answer_d";
}
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    // insert values into mysql database 
    $answer = "answer_m";

}
```

then I want to echo the variable `$answer` in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: You can't use a return statement in an `if`. Your code seems to be fine, is there any other code that you can show us so we can help you?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then the issue is that the $answer variable doesn't exist outside of the scope of the if statements. Try defining $answer alongside your other variables such as $gameid and then updating the value within the if statements.

Comment: `if` blocks don't have their own scope. Variables initialized in an if block are available outside of the block as well. Also see this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243991/

Answer (score 0):

at first initialize the variable value. then you echo this variable after all condition then you understand which if block your code enter or not

```
$gameid = $_GET['gameid'];
$answer = '';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$questionid = $_GET['questionid'];

if (isset($_GET['gameid'])) {
$answer = "answer_d";
}
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    // insert values into mysql database 
    $answer = "answer_m";

}
```