# PHP response partially working when loaded by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get to pass values to a PHP page which would respond with PHP code to be loaded. My problem is the returned PHP code partially works.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'bundles_drop.php',
  data: {
   time_selected:value,
   networkType:networkType,
  },
  dataType : 'html',
  success: function (response) {
   // We get the element having id of display_info and put the response inside it
    $("#bundles").html(response);
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
    if( isset( $_POST['time_selected'] ) )
    {

     $duration_selected = $_POST['time_selected'];
     //$duration_selected = "day";
     $client_network =$_POST['networkType']
    }
```

When I receive the AJAX post, echoing the variables can be done within the first lines of code . My issue is afew lines of code later, the variables loose their values (i tried echoing at different parts of code but only works with the first few lines).

And the variables only maintain their values if I hard code them and dont use the POST values. eg

```
$duration_selected = "day";
```

Any ideas on what may be causing the loss of POST values?

FULL PHP CODE:

```
<?php

include 'arrays.php';

global $netMap;
global $netArray;
global $cM;

global $contABB;

if( isset( $_POST['time_selected'] ) )
{

    $duration_selected = $_POST['time_selected'];
    //$duration_selected = "day";
    $client_net =$_POST['netType'];
    //$duration_selected = "ugmtn";




    $ds = $duration_selected;
    $cn = $client_net;


    $quantityOfCardsArray = array();
    $bundle_duration = array();
    $numberOfnets = count($netMap[$contABB]);
    $netNames = array();
    $net = array();
    $netNames = $netMap[$contABB];



    for($i=0;$i<$numberOfnets;$i++)
    {
            $thisnet=$netMap[$contABB][$i];
            $numD=count($cardMap[$contABB][$thisnet]);
            $bundle_duration = $cardMap[$contABB][$thisnet];
            $netName=$netArray[$contABB]["$thisnet"]["netName"]; 



            for($j=0;$j<$numD;$j++)
            {
                $cardIndex=$cardMap[$contABB]["$thisnet"]["$j"];
                //var_dump($priceInLocal=$netArray[$contABB]["$thisnet"][0]["$cardIndex"]);

            }
    }       
?>
                  <label id="bundlelbl"  for="bundle">Please select a bundle</label>
                  <select id="bundle" name="bundle" required>
<?php



    foreach($netNames as $index => $net){

        if($net == $client_net)
        {

            $net_bundle=$netArray[$contABB]["$net"];

            foreach($net_bundle as $value)
            {
                $value = (array) $value;

                foreach ($value as $time => $bundle_details)
                {
                    if($time == $duration_selected)
                    {
                            $detail_count = count($bundle_details);
                            $bundle_details = (array) $bundle_details;

                            //var_dump($bundle_details);

                            foreach($bundle_details as $data_value => $data_details)
                            {
                                $data_details = (array) $data_details;

                                echo "<option value='".  $data_details['Item'] ."'> ". $data_details['Item'] ." worth ". $data_details['pr'] . "</option>";


                            }

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
?>

  </select>


 <fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

I could echo out the post values up till

```
    ?>
                  <label id="bundlelbl"  for="bundle">Please select a bundle</label>
                  <select id="bundle" name="bundle" required>
<?php
```

beyond that point echo doesnt display at all.

SOLVED:

I had placed a foreach loop within an if statement when for what I intended it was supposed to be the other way round. Thanks

Comment: Show the rest of your PHP code. It may be a scope issue.

Comment: Can you post the `few lines of code later`? If your values are getting set in that if statement then it's likely something after is overwriting them.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable in a scoped area (in your if statement) they are only accessible within the if. declare them before and set them whithin, like this:

```
$duration_selected = '';
$client_network = '';

if( isset( $_POST['time_selected'] ) )
{
    $duration_selected = $_POST['time_selected'];
    //$duration_selected = "day";
    $client_network =$_POST['networkType'];
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. If/else statements have the same scope as the surrounding code. However, if it doesn't hit the if statement, it won't be defined. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243991/if-you-create-a-variable-inside-a-if-statement-is-it-available-outside-the-if-st

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$duration_selected` and `$client_network` outside your `if( isset( $_POST['time_selected'] ) )` block then it will be undefined unless it is executed at least once.

Therefore make sure the code that access the previous two variables is running inside the `if` block mentioned above.

Example :

```
if( isset( $_POST['time_selected'] ) )
    {

     $duration_selected = $_POST['time_selected'];
     //$duration_selected = "day";
     $client_network =$_POST['networkType']

     $another_variable = $duration_selected + 'something'; // correct
    }

    $another_variable = $duration_selected + 'something'; // wrong
```

Comment: Incorrect. If/else statements have the same scope as the surrounding code. However, if it doesn't hit the if statement, it won't be defined. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243991/if-you-create-a-variable-inside-a-if-statement-is-it-available-outside-the-if-st

Comment: You said it **If it doesn't hit the If block at least once, that mean those variables aren't defined and that is what am talking about here**

Comment: You say that they are only accessible inside the IF block. That's incorrect. If it hits the IF block, they're defined and useable anywhere afterwards. If it does not hit the IF block, they aren't defined. In any case, it's good practice to either define it before, also define it in an else block, or use a ternary instead.

Comment: You're right @aynber i forgot to mention the case when the IF block is visited at least once, thanks for your comments.